# Firebase Analytics / Firebase Crashlytics - reporting errors

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics, firebase-analytics

I am working on an iOS app that uses Firebase Analytics and Firebase Crashlytics. I wonder what is the best way to report errors. Crashes are reported automatically, so probably I should log errors as events? I am talking about caught cases where for example the data from the server cannot be parsed and used for some reason, but the app does not crash, just doesn't work as expected.

I am looking at the predefined event `app_exception` and its predefined parameter `firebase_event_origin`. Is this the right way to do it and if yes what should be logged as `firebase_event_origin`? Or should I define some custom event with custom params, or maybe there is a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm doing something like this in my project and it's working great:

```
public protocol ErrorRecorder {
    func recordError(_ error: NSError, userInfo: [String: Any]?)
}

extension Crashlytics: ErrorRecorder {
    public func recordError(_ error: NSError, userInfo: [String: Any]?) {
        Crashlytics.sharedInstance().recordError(error, withAdditionalUserInfo: userInfo)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I've missed this option on Crashlytics, just tried it and it works well. Thanks.